# MYSQL запрос для переноса данных из одной таблицы в другую

Tags: mysql, sql

Пожалуйста, помогите создать запрос в Mysql для переноса данных 1-го конкретного поля для все значений из старой базы данных в новую, по ключевому полю.

Структура такая:

Старая база bd_old.table_old

Новая база bd_new.table_new

В таблицах обеих баз данных есть поле(столбец) 'description'

Нужно из старой базы все значения этого поля перенести в новую.

Есть ключевое поле 'id' значения которого совпадают в обеих базах.

Comment: джойн по полю и апдейт

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если значения уже есть в новой базе и речь только про обновление, то можно

1. Через джоин

```
UPDATE `bd_new.table_new` new
    INNER JOIN bd_old.table_old old ON new.id = old.id
SET new.description = old.description;
```

2. Через сабквери (в большинстве случаев более ресурсоемкий чем join)

```
UPDATE `bd_new.table_new` new
SET description = (
    SELECT old.description
    from bd_old.table_old old
    WHERE old.id = new.id
)
```

Comment: подзапрос тут не шибко продуктивен будет.

Comment: Вы правы, он более ресурсоемкий. Но я и не знаю сколько тут записей, что бы говорить о перформансе. Может речь о 10 строках. Я написал про подзапрос, что бы показать, что такой способ есть, в первую очередь для людей, у которых связь может быть более вариативна.

Comment: я в основном к тому, что вариант с подзапросом будет выполняться для каждой строки таблицы, не зависимо от того, есть ли соответствие в старой. Более того, если в старой соответствия нет, то мы получим NULL значение. Так что вариант имеет место быть, но указывать его лучше просто вторым в списке, или как то описать приоритеты.

Comment: Можно много спорить, выстраивая домыслы из того как может быть у топикстартера, не видя картины. В большинстве случаев джоин работает быстрее, чем подзапросы. Но SQL всегда строит план выполнения, поэтому надо смотреть explain. Независимо от того, как вы пишете свой запрос, SQL Server всегда преобразует его в план выполнения. Опять же, из-за объемов таблиц, подзапросы могут выйграть, если у нас одинаковое количество записей и таблицы просто огромные. Подзапрос одного поля с лимитом 1 займет меньше ОЗУ чем join.

Comment: Но думаю вы правы, с таким вопросом, вряд ли у нас что-то "сверх", добавил комментарий и поменял порядок, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте UPDATE совместно с JOIN. таким образом сразу отфильтруете все записи, которые имеют соответствия, и только их и обновите

```
UPDATE t1
INNER JOIN t2 on t2.id = t1.id
SET t1.description = t2.description
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]